# Sending a POST request without API iOS

Tags: html, ios, asp.net, post, afnetworking

I have been failing for a time now, maybe someone has a small advice that can help.

I am trying to fetch data from a website that does not offer an API, what I am trying to do, is get the html page and parse it to get the data.
I have done this before when the form on the website is of type GET, but when it's POST it's not working, I am using AFNetworking and also tried without it. The page is in .NET (.aspx).

More info:
-The asps page (html data in browser), opens and there is a textfield and an select input, upon submitting a post request is send and a table is added to that web page, but on iOS I am getting the old page without the table.

-I tried changing the User-Agent, setting the Host, Origin, Referer, Content-Type.. everything.

When I am suspicious about is the .NET stuff, I have never worked with it, but the input tag's name are weird, plus there is an extra few inputs that are hidden that contain weird data.

Thanks for any help, if you want me to post any code please tell, but it's the same code shown inside a hundred stack overflow question.

Comment: Are you sure that the a POST request is sent? The page is reloaded? From your description it seems that the request is handled by some ajax/javascript code.

Comment: yes it is send, on the browser the page reloads, also the textfield in the new page has the original data in it, I get that, but the table containing the data I want is missing.